# IList<T> does not have "where"

Tags: c#, linq, list, ilist

In a specific project at my work, I have a method that returns IList. But this interface does not contain where, or FindAll filters. However, when I open a new project, IList contains all. What is the difference?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Did you import System.Linq ?

Comment: @bileyazan - I agree with @Will Dean, it's important to accept answers that help you out from SO.  It doesn't just give the answerer reputation, it lets future googlers know which answer helped you figure out your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Nope.  `IEnumerable<T>` has "where" as an extension method.

Assuming your project is **.Net 3.5 or greater**, you need to have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` you mean. :) The plain old `IEnumerable` is not supported by LINQ - you have to do `Cast`/`OfType` first.

Comment: @Noldorin: Yeah, I actually had `<T>`, but I forgot to put it in a code block and StackOverflow lost it... probably got rendered as a HTML tag.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You might find this useful:  [LINQ, Where() vs FindAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938204/linq-where-vs-findall)

Answer (score 1):

Check .NET Framework of opened framework, may be its .NET Fx 2.

System.Linq added in 3.5

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a basic discussion of extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) in general.  As mentioned by others, the Where method is an extension method found in the System.Linq namespace so you need to import it in order to have intellisense detect the existence of those methods.