# Finding 'pairs' in a List

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of Buttons and I want to get the two elements that are 'equal':

```
for (int i = 0; i < Memory.Count; i++ )
{
     piezas = Memory.FindAll(s => (s.Name != Memory[i].Name && Utilidades.CompareImage(s.Image, Memory[i].Image)));
}
```

This is supposed (if I'm not wrong) the list with the two elements that have different Name but are using the same Image. I'm more than sure that such elements exists... but I don't know why this doesn't work.

"Utilidades.CompareImage" is an static method:

```
public static bool CompareImage(Image firstImage, Image secondImage)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            firstImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            String firstBitmap = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            ms.Position = 0;

                secondImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            String secondBitmap = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

            if (firstBitmap.Equals(secondBitmap))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

I've tested the method before and it's working as intented.

Can you please help me?

Comment: How are you checking the result of your code? Try to add some debug statements showing intermediate results. The code looks like 'it might just work'...

Comment: Using breakpoints and the var is NEVER 2 and it should be unless my predicate is wrong.

Comment: Well it should be 'a list of two elements', not 2.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wasn't comparing 'var == 2' but instead 'var.Count == 2'.

But I'm not specifying things correctly. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, edit the question. "Expected=2, Actual=..."

Comment: BTW I removed the linq tag because .FindAll is not a linq extension. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938204/linq-where-vs-findall

Comment: Ah indeed you should expect only one element, not two, as pad mentions.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
for (int i = 0; i < Memory.Count; i++ )
{
    var piezas = Memory.FindAll(s => (s.Name != Memory[i].Name 
          && Utilidades.CompareImage(s.Image, Memory[i].Image)));
}
```

creates a new 'piezas' every time and then doesn't use it.
Also you are checking all combinations twice.

So do you want to find all pairs, the first pair or maybe something in between?

A quick fix, but far from perfect,

```
for (int i = 0; i < Memory.Count; i++ )
{
    var piezas = Memory.FindAll(s => (s.Name != Memory[i].Name 
          && Utilidades.CompareImage(s.Image, Memory[i].Image)));

    if (piezas.Count > 0)
    {
        // use piezas[0] somehow
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm really sorry for not stating that. I just want the first pair, (and I use 'piezas' after, but I didn't copy that because It is not relevant.

Comment: Then don't mislead by declaring it with `var` either.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I was using that. It just that piezas.Count is never two. Is my FindAll 'query' right?

Comment: `piezas.Count = 1` means you found a similar element with `Memory[i]`. So it is totally correct.

Answer (score 1):

It seems no one mentioned SelectMany yet:

```
var pieza = Memory.SelectMany((m, i) => 
Memory.Where((m2, j) => i < j && m.Name != m2.Name && 
Utilidades.CompareImage(m.Image, m2.Image))
.Select(m2 => Tuple.Create(m, m2))).First();
```

if you want all pairs, not just one, replace the final First() call to ToList() or something like that.