# Linq FindAll and Where returns different results

Tags: c#, linq

I have two different types of objects that have ID fields with potentially matching IDs. The FindAll operation returns the correct non-matching objects whereas the Where operation returns all objects. Can someone help me understand why?

```
var _kenticoIDs = new HashSet<string>(_kenticoSessions.Select(p => p.AttendeeInteractiveSessionID));
var list = _aiSessionIDList.FindAll(p => !_kenticoIDs.Contains(p.SessionID));
var ienum = _aiSessionIDList.Where(p => !_kenticoIDs.Contains(p.SessionID));
```

EDIT: If I perform a .ToList() on the resultA variable then resulting list is the same as the result variable. However when I inspect the two variables (result/resultA) before the .ToList() one has 6 values and one has 63 values. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Your code is *horribly* formatted at the moment, to the point of unreadability. Please fix it.

Comment: Are you saying that `_aiSessionIDList.Where(p => !_kenticoIDs.Contains(p.SessionID))` returns every item in `_aiSessionIDList`, even if an item in the list has an ID not in the `_kenticoIDs` hash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Where` and `FindAll` are equivalent, except that in terms of execution, `Where` is deferred, but `FindAll` is immediate.

Source: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938204/linq-where-vs-findall) SO thread.

Comment: I had looked at that exact question earlier and had seen the deferred execution but had mistakenly believed that inspecting it in the debugger was the same as an on-demand operation.

Comment: Oh ok. Next time, when dealing with LINQ variables, be conscious of the 'deferred' execution context. A good trick is to call the 'Count()' method to force immediate evaluation in the 'Watch' windows.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of feel like an idiot. It wasn't until I did the ToList() did I realize that I just wasn't doing anything to actually evaluate the resultset.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue you are having is understanding Linq.  [Where is a Linq extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938204/linq-where-vs-findall) whereas FindAll is a List method.  Linq expressions are not evaluated until they are enumerated over, or turned into a list/array.