# .Count not supported when doing a find on child collection complex object field value

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core

I have a find query that when from this

```
!CurrentUser.SentMatchRequest.Contains(OtherProfile.userId)
```

To this

```
CurrentUser.SentMatchRequest.FindAll(x => x.Id==OtherProfile.userId).Count==0
```

However, the query fails by stating .count is not supported.
Before the collection used to be a simple string array and now it changed to a complex object

```
public class info
{
 public string Id {get;set;}
 public DateTime TimeStamp {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test if your query's result contains at least one element, better use `Any()`, like so:

Instead of...

```
CurrentUser.SentMatchRequest.FindAll(x => x.Id==OtherProfile.userId).Count==0
```

better use...

```
!CurrentUser.SentMatchRequest.FindAll(x => x.Id==OtherProfile.userId).Any()
```

If you really need the count, you can get it like this:

```
CurrentUser.SentMatchRequest.FindAll(x => x.Id==OtherProfile.userId).ToList().Count==0
```

The reason is, that `IEnumerable<T>` can be used to iterate through a collection, but the number of elements in the collection remains unknown until you reach the end.
T get the count of elements, you must iterate through the whole collection, that's what happens with the `ToList()` method, it forces LINQ to exactly do this.
If you only need to know, if the collection contains elements at all, this apporach is inefficient. `Any()` however, does what you need: It checks, if the collection contains at least one element, so this operation does not have t iterate through the whole collection.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that makes sense in regards to the use of count. However, I did change my query to the above suggestion but it throws the following error: "The method FindAll is not supported in the expression tree"

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938204/linq-where-vs-findall

Answer (score 0):

You can use (Count with () will iterate one more time over your collection) .Count() == 0; or Count() == 0;  instead but is realy better to use .Any(x => x.Id.Equals(OtherProfile.userId));