# C# I want to find out if numbers in my List are divisable by 3 without making an array out of it

Tags: c#, arrays, list, modulo

[image]

I did this already by turning the list into an arrays, but how do i do this without an array

Comment: Please paste code as text, not as image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why not just use `foreach` on `nummern`?

Comment: You are already using an array hidden inside `List<>`. So what is the point of saying not to use an array? Did you mean to say not to use a loop or something like that?

Comment: The number of elements in a List is given by the Count property - so instead of creating an array use the list in the for loop checking for "i < nummern.Count;".

Answer (score 1):

You could use `foreach`:

```
foreach (int num in nummern) {
  if (num % 3 == 0)
    // your code goes here
}
```

or with an lambda to get rid of the if:

```
foreach (int num in nummern.FindAll(n => n % 3 == 0)) {
  // your code goes here
}
```

or directly create a new List:

```
List<int> nummernMod3 = nummern.FindAll( n => n % 3 == 0 );
```

Note that you could also use `Where` instead of `FindAll`. There is a [separate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938204/linq-where-vs-findall) that may help you decide.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use

```
var ziffern = nummern.Where(n => n%3 == 0);
```

Then you could iterate on it (it's an Enumerable) or convert it to array or to list (`.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`) or whatever you need...

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach

```
foreach (int x in nummern)
            {
                if (x % 3 ==0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already a list, so there is no actual need to convert it to an Array

```
    var list = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6};
    
    // Method 1 - for loop
    for(var i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (list[i] % 3 == 0) Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    }
    
    // Method 2 - foreach loop
    foreach(var num in list)
    {
        if (num % 3 == 0) Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
    
    // Method 3 - using LinQ
    var results = list.Where(x => x % 3 == 0); // this will result in a new list of results
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results));
```